# imprimir QRcode diretamente impressora Zebra pelo python

Tags: python, python-2.7, qrcode

estou gerando qrcodes pelo python, so que quero imprimir diretamente na impressora zebra de etiquetas, eu ja consigo imprimir palavras contidas em uma entry, mas quando tento imprimir o qrcode da erro:
codigo:

```
def printQrCode(self):
            img = os.path.join(self.defaultLocation, self.qrPhotoTxt.get() + ".jpg")
            image1 = Image.open(img)
            basewidth = 240
            wpercent = (basewidth / float(image1.size[0]))
            hsize = int((float(image1.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
            image = image1.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
            self.imgPanel.create_image(2, 2, anchor=NW, image=self.photo)
            self.imgPanel.image = self.photo
            label = """
            ^XA

            ^FO10,15
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD
            """+image+"""
            ^FS

            ^FO10,60
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD
            Test Zebra
            ^FS

            ^FO10,105
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD
            Test Zebra
            ^FS


            ^XZ
            """

            from zebra import zebra
            z = zebra('ZDesigner ZT230-200dpi ZPL')
            z.output(label)
```

erro em questao:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.6/QRcodeTKinter.py", line 103, in printQrCode
        """+image+"""
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu filho, você está tentando concatenar uma imagem a uma string, o que não faz sentido. Mude o label para:

```
    label = """
            ^XA

            ^FO10,15
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD

            ^FS

            ^FO10,60
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD
            Test Zebra
            ^FS

            ^FO10,105
            ^A0,40,20
            ^FD
            Test Zebra
            ^FS


            ^XZ
            """
```

Isso eliminará o **TypeError** em questão (Não se concatena uma string a um objeto que não comporta o método especial __ str __). Procure pelos manuais no site da Zebra pra descobrir como mandar a imagem para a Zebra. Seja como for, **não use** concatenação.

https://www.zebra.com/us/en.html